# Not able to execute my SparkStreaming Program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, spark-streaming

I have written the following Scala code and my platform is Cloudera CDH 5.2.1 on CentOS 6.5

**Tutorial.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import TutorialHelper._

object Tutorial {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val checkpointDir = TutorialHelper.getCheckPointDirectory()
        val consumerKey = "..."
        val consumerSecret = "..."
        val accessToken = "..."
        val accessTokenSecret = "..."
        try {
            TutorialHelper.configureTwitterCredentials(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
            val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkContext(), Seconds(1))
            val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
            val tweetText = tweets.map(tweet => tweet.getText())
            tweetText.print()
            ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
            ssc.start()
            ssc.awaitTermination()
        } finally {
            //ssc.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

My build.sbt file looks like

```
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

name := "Tutorial"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.0.0"
)

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"

assemblySettings

mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                    => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                   => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I also created a file called projects/plugin.sbt which has the following content

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-cross-building" % "0.8.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.1")
```

and project/build.scala

```
import sbt._

object Plugins extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) dependsOn(
    uri("git://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly.git#0.9.1")
  )
}
```

after this I can build my "uber" assembly by using

```
sbt assembly
```

now I run my code using

```
sudo -u hdfs spark-submit --class Tutorial --master local /tmp/Tutorial-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the error

```
Configuring Twitter OAuth
        Property twitter4j.oauth.accessToken set as [...]
        Property twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret set as [...]
        Property twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret set as [...]
        Property twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey set as [...]

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/jars/spark-assembly-1.1.0-cdh5.2.1-hadoop2.5.0-cdh5.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
14/12/21 16:04:30 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1419199472000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1419199473000 ms
-------------------------------------------

14/12/21 16:04:33 ERROR ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Error stopping receiver 0org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:52)
org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.log(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:59)
org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.logInfo(TwitterInputDStream.scala:60)
org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStop(TwitterInputDStream.scala:101)
org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.stopReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:136)
org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.stop(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:112)
org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:127)
org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:106)
org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:264)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sbt assembly plugin to prepare "assembled" jar file with all dependencies. It should contain all twitter util classes.

Links:
 1. https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly
 2. http://prabstechblog.blogspot.com/2014/04/creating-single-jar-for-spark-project.html
 3. http://eugenezhulenev.com/blog/2014/10/18/run-tests-in-standalone-spark-cluster/

Or you can take a look at my Spark-Twitter project, it has configured sbt-assembly plugin: http://eugenezhulenev.com/blog/2014/11/20/twitter-analytics-with-spark/

Comment: I tried everything listed in the blogs above. but still got an error. I have updated my post to list my new steps. if possible please let me know where I am going wrong...

Comment: Looks like slf4j included in assembly by transitive dependency from spark, I suggest you to use dependency-tree plugin for sbt to find the source of this dependency. Also you can take a look how I solved this problem with excluding dependencies in sbt: https://github.com/pellucidanalytics/tweet-driven-comparable-companies/blob/master/project/Dependency.scala#L47

Answer (score 0):

CDH 5.2 packages Spark 1.1.0, but you build.sbt is using 1.0.0. Update the versions below and rebuild should fix your problem.

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.0" % "provided",
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.0.0"
 )
```